# Friendly URLs redirection using regular expression

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the follow challenge,  I have friendly URLs for pages in a site:

/subdir1/subdir2/uniqueID/

Some of the pages can be cached as html (not all) so we cached them in html files in a folder:

/cache/uniqueID.html

So I need to show this pages only if they exists in cache dire based on friendly url, my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ !-f 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$3.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ /cache/$3.html [L]
```

This works but have 2 problems:
1) if a subdir name has a "-" or "_"  wont work.
2) if last "/" is not present won't work.

Also Im not a regexpr savvy so for sure there is a better way to do this, any help is really appreciate.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak your regex to allow hyphen & underscore. Also remove a redundant `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$3\.html -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ cache/$3.html [L]
```